# Optimizing a shared buffer in a producer/consumer multithreaded environment

Tags: c, performance, multithreading, caching, shared-memory

I have some project where I have a single producer thread which writes events into a buffer, and an additional single consumer thread which takes events from the buffer. My goal is to optimize this thing **for a single dual-core machine** to achieve maximum throughput.

Currently, I am using some simple lock-free ring buffer (lock-free is possible since I have only one consumer and one producer thread and therefore the pointers are only updated by a single thread).

```
#define BUF_SIZE 32768

struct buf_t { volatile int writepos; volatile void * buffer[BUF_SIZE]; 
    volatile int readpos;) };

void produce (buf_t *b, void * e) {
    int next = (b->writepos+1) % BUF_SIZE;
    while (b->readpos == next); // queue is full. wait
    b->buffer[b->writepos] = e; b->writepos = next;
}

void * consume (buf_t *b) {
    while (b->readpos == b->writepos); // nothing to consume. wait
    int next = (b->readpos+1) % BUF_SIZE;
    void * res = b->buffer[b->readpos]; b->readpos = next;
    return res;
}

buf_t *alloc () {
    buf_t *b = (buf_t *)malloc(sizeof(buf_t));
    b->writepos = 0; b->readpos = 0; return b;
}
```

However, this implementation is not yet fast enough and should be optimized further. I've tried with different `BUF_SIZE` values and got some speed-up. Additionaly, I've moved `writepos` before the `buffer` and `readpos` after the `buffer` to ensure that both variables are on different cache lines which resulted also in some speed.

What I need is a speedup of about 400 %. Do you have any ideas how I could achieve this using things like padding etc?

Comment: "lock-free is possible since I have only one consumer and one producer thread" - what happens if the consumer and producer thread collide?

Comment: How much CPU is burned in the busy-waits?

Comment: Busy waits??? You don't ask how to make it faster if you have busy waits.

Comment: @mitch: When the consumer and producer thread collide, one thread is forced to be in the while spin-lock. Consistency is ensured since the buffer is read / written before the read/write position pointer is updated.

@marcelo: In my testing environment, the producer spams random values inside the queue while the consumer does nothing else then consuming them. Therefore, the processes shouldn't wait that much that it should be worried about. Additionaly, the two processes run on different cores of the CPU, so they shouldn't afflict each other's CPU time.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you have multiple CPUs, you will probably need a memory barrier between produce and consume.  This will slow you down (maybe a lot), but without it, the consumer may see the write index move prior to the data being written to the buffer, and retrieve invalid data.

Comment: What do you mean "for a single machine"? Threads are within a process and, usually, a process runs on one and only one machine. Usually the question is __how many CPU cores__ you have, as MT bugs often only show up in a multi-core scenario, where work is really done in parallel and you have memory caching issues.

Comment: @Aidan Cully: That depends on the architecture.  On x86, for example, you are guaranteed that writes are not reordered with respect to other writes by the same CPU.

Comment: It is on a dual core machine.

Comment: How much time is actually spent in the buffer, and how much of that is busy waiting  ? Maybe you could easily  get your 400% elsewhere.

Comment: the measured performance is only for the produce/consume implementation. busy waiting should not make any problems since the threads run on different cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented the optimizations in the first code block of cafs answer. They actually gave some little speed up (thank you), however it is not yet enough. The second optimization which results in the cache being filled by column instead of by row results in a worse performance.

The idea of the consumer lagging behind the producer did not gave any speedup.

Now, I'm at 300%.

An additional change I have made was some hack regarding the volatile writepos and readpos variables:

```
void produce (void * e) {
    unsigned int oldpos = buffer.writepos;
    unsigned int next = (oldpos+1) % BUF_SIZE;
    while (next == buffer.rpos) { // rpos is not volatile
        buffer.rpos = buffer.readpos;
        usleep(1);
    }
    buffer.buffer[oldpos] = e; buffer.writepos = next;
}
```

and similar for the consume().

Additional changes to the struct lead to the following new buffer struct (in the global scope as it was suggested in one answer instead of on the heap).

```
#define STRIDE 16
#define STEPS 524288

struct buf_t {
    volatile unsigned int writepos;
    int offset [STRIDE - 1];
    unsigned int wpos;
    int offset2 [STRIDE - 1];
    volatile void * buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    int offset4 [STRIDE];
    volatile unsigned int readpos;
    int offset3 [STRIDE - 1];
    unsigned int rpos;
}
```

which gave the 300% speedup which was missing and pushed it below the performance limit I had to achieve.

If you have some additional hacks which could be used to increase the performance further, don't hesitate to post them also :-)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one optimisation I can see: in `consume()`, you don't need to be fetching `b->readpos` continously, since the thread calling `consume()` is the only one that can update it anyway.  Because it's `volatile`, the compiler can't optimise all those fetches away, so you'll need to do it explicitly:

```
void * consume (buf_t *b) {
    int rp = b->readpos;
    while (rp == b->writepos); // nothing to consume. wait
    int next = (rp + 1) % BUF_SIZE;
    void * res = b->buffer[rp]; b->readpos = next;
    return res;
}
```

You should also step through your buffer in strides of at least a cacheline each, otherwise you'll get cachelines ping-ponging between the two CPUs (as one CPU wants the cacheline to read `b->buffer[n]` and 15 times out of 16 the other invalidates it to write `b->buffer[n+1]`).  Eg:

```
#define STRIDE 16
#define STEPS 2048
#define BUF_SIZE (STRIDE * STEPS)

#define TO_INDEX(n) (STRIDE * (((n) + 1) % STEPS) + (((n) + 1) / STEPS))

void produce (buf_t *b, void * e) {
    unsigned wp = b->writepos;
    unsigned next = (wp + 1) % BUF_SIZE;
    while (b->readpos == next); // queue is full. wait
    b->buffer[TO_INDEX(wp)] = e; b->writepos = next;
}

void * consume (buf_t *b) {
    unsigned rp = b->readpos;
    while (rp == b->writepos); // nothing to consume. wait
    unsigned next = (rp + 1) % BUF_SIZE;
    void * res = b->buffer[TO_INDEX(rp)]; b->readpos = next;
    return res;
}
```

Got to be worth a try, anyway.  (Note that as long as `STRIDE` and `STEPS` are powers of 2, the scary-looking division and modulus in `TO_INDEX()` can be optimised to a shift and a bitwise-and, but only if the operands are `unsigned` - hence I suggest changing those types accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using a machine with more than one processor or core.  If not then your busy waits are going to hurt things.  They may hurt anyway if you are running under an OS that decides that you don't sleep enough and bumps down your dynamic priority and there are other programs running.

You need to collect data on how full your buffer gets.  At a certain point too big starts to hurt your cache too.

If you use a global array rather than allocating it from the heap then the pointer to the buffer becomes a pointer literal and both threads won't have to read that pointer value from the same place in cache because it will just be shoved into the code.

If throughput is what's important to you (at the expense of latency) and cache really is playing a big roll, then you might consider letting the consumer lag the producer so that they aren't trying to read and write from the same place in the buffer.

You may want to change the interface to your consumer function so that it can consume in cache size (or multiple of) sized chunks (this plays nice with the consumer lagging the producer suggestion I made above) in addition to individual or partial cache line chunks.  Try to keep the consumption cache aligned.  If you think of the available data as a snake, then it's possible for the head and the tail to be unaligned.  You should only consume an unaligned tail when there is no other data to consume.  If you can consume any other data in a call to consume then you should just leave the tail for the next call.

Other than that and what has been mentioned by caf I'd have to suspect that whatever is happening outside the of this code has to be playing a bigger role.